# PayPal SDK Direct payments details in PayPal

Tags: android, paypal, sdk

I'm no expert but I created an android app that accepts a payment for a download then gives the customer that download once payment is confirmed.  I used the PayPal SDK for Android, their example app is here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK which I am basing my code on.

My little app works well, I'm very pleased with it.  I have one BIG issue, should a customer want a refund I go into PayPal to issue it, if they paid via PayPal login it's easy, scroll down, look for their name or email and click refund.   If they paid by direct card payment it's very different.  If you go into papa and look you can spot the card payments quite clearly, they have no name or email attached to them, in fact there is no personal detail to associate the payment to them at all.

How on earth is that acceptable?  I can't locate a customers payment in PayPal to even know if they really are a customer.  Surely it should at leafs be able to give you a name?

Am I missing something in the SDK?  Is there perhaps a field I'm not populating that puts detail into the Paypal transaction?

Any help and / or code snippets would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Wanted to let you know that I understand the issue and am surprised that this is the behavior.  Am working internally to find resolution.

Comment: Thanks :)  
We have since discovered that you can actually search for the Credit card huber in PayPal and it will actually find the transaction.  Issue being of course that we can't really ask for peoples Credit card numbers all the time, not really secure to be asking for their card numbers by email anyway.

I look forward to hearing that a fix has been found :)

Comment: Any further progress on this?  Still seems a very silly shortfall from PayPal to not put the purchasers name on the PayPal transaction list.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, the Transaction is of no use when the user paid by Credit card, they don't get to know their transaction id and I can't distinguish all the transactions on the paypal website to know.  This is what the whole problem is, it's a sort of half payment solution, yes it takes money and paypal make their fee, but if we need to refund the customer we cannot track them to be able to do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, your app should correlate the payment ID returned by the SDK with your customer/sale and communicate this back to your server.  This way, you can use the payment ID to get the associated transaction ID to refund.